# Unexpected token "=" reported while running eslint on arrow functions

Tags: javascript, eslint, class-fields, ecmascript-2021

I have a JavaScript class and inside it I have an async method which looks like below.

```
class ABC {
    func = async () => { //----line 10
        //some code
    }
    func2 = () => { //----line 11
        //some code 
    }
}
```

When I run ESLint it's reporting one error. The application itself is working as expected.

```
unexpected token '=' at line 10 (& 11)
```

**eslintrc.json**

```
{
   "env":{
       "es2021":true
    }
}
```

What do I need to do in order to get rid of these lint errors and still keep these methods as arrow functions?

ESLint version: `eslint :"^7.32.0"`

Comment: the issue is with running lint only on local. The app code is working fine.

Comment: Also there are quite a few search results when I search for that error in combination with "eslint" -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: eslint :"^7.32.0"

Comment: Why are you using this syntax at all? If those as class functions, just declare them as such. `class ABC { async func(...) { ... } func2(...) { ... }}`. Don't declare them as instance properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade to ESLint 8 and add this setting to your .eslintrc:

```json
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 2022
}
```

**Reason:** you are using [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). Support for class fields syntax in ESLint [has been introduced](https://eslint.org/blog/2021/06/whats-coming-in-eslint-8.0.0#support-for-es2022-class-fields-top-level-await-and-regexp-matching-indices) with version 8.

Note that the specification of class fields, although [already finalized](https://ecmascript-daily.github.io/2021/04/20/class-fields-to-stage-4-per-2021-04-19-tc39-tc39-proposals-5435781) in April 2021, will be published with ECMAScript 2022, expected next year.